# android studio preview and when it works on phone is different

Tags: android, android-studio, screen, android-virtual-device

In the Android Studio design preview, my layout fits perfectly on screen.
Even when I played it though `AVD`, it fits well.
But when I connect my phone with Android studio and run it, it doesn't fit in my phone screen. It seems like `centerCrop` is on the whole screen. all layouts have the same problem.

I'm using a Samsung s8+. Preview setting is also Samsung s8+ which Android Studio provides.

At first, I thought that this problem is caused by 18.5:9 ratio of my phone. But in that case, the screen should be cut only at bottom and top. But it seems like `centerCrop` is enlarging based on the center?

The screenshot on the left is what I see on the preview and on the right is what I see on my physical phone:

[image: Screenshots of Android Studio design preview vs physical phone]

Comment: Try to build your application and install direct to your device and check if you have the same problem.

Comment: Please edit your post to add details (e.g. XML layout) instead of posting it as comments

Answer (score 0):

Two Solutions:

1. Go for Linear layout if you don't bother layout hierarchy and coding style, as it fits for the most number of screens.
2. The design which you saw in the emulator will not be same in Actual mobile device in all cases. So try to debug your app in actual mobile device and design accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your custom emulator has the same settings ( Height, Width, RAM ) as your phone.